# FlutterConfig.loadEnvVariables() is not working (flutter pub global run rename breaks app)

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, environment-variables, api-key

I'm using flutter_config to read my api keys from .env file (I know it's not the most secure way but I'm just prototyping app).

That's part of my main.dart code

```
import 'package:flutter_config/flutter_config.dart';

void main() async
{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  print("loading variables");
  await FlutterConfig.loadEnvVariables();
  print("variables loaded");
  print(FlutterConfig.variables);
  print(FlutterConfig.get("GOOGLE_MAPS_UNRESTRICTED_API_KEY"));
  ...
}
```

and that's the output

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Reading env from: .env
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

I/flutter (13946): loading variables
E/narq.foodNearb(13946): Invalid ID 0x00000000.
D/FlutterConfig(13946): Could not access BuildConfig
I/flutter (13946): variables loaded
I/flutter (13946): {}
I/flutter (13946): FlutterConfig Variables are Empty
I/flutter (13946): Ensure you have a .env file and you
I/flutter (13946): have loaded the variables
I/flutter (13946): null
D/EGL_emulation(13946): app_time_stats: avg=18.39ms min=2.57ms max=84.79ms count=57
```

**Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?**

I guess it stopped working when I've added app icon while following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0GNuoCOtaQ).

**UPDATE**

I rolled back to previous version and found out this command:

```
flutter pub global run rename --bundleId com.new.app_id
```

Causes this to happen but still don't know why and how to fix it.

**UPDATE 2**

Build version throws the same error even without running flutter rename.

Comment: could you share the path of the .env file? and the content (without the actual values of your secrets)

Comment: .env is in project's root folder so my_app_name/.env and it looks like this "GOOGLE_MAPS_UNRESTRICTED_API_KEY=abcdSuperSecretKey"